# dead key after switching two keys with xmodmap

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

My keyboard switches the (German) keys [^] and [<], so I want to switch the two keys.

I identified the keycodes using xev and created a file `~/.xmodmap` containing

```
keycode 94 = asciicircum degree
keycode 49 = less greater
```

When executing `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` hardware key 94 now correctly outputs "^" instead of "<". Unfortunately the other key does not output any character at all.

xev returns the following output when the key is pressed

```
KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x4b, subw 0x0, time 258843335, (169,-12), root:(185,111),
    state 0x4000, keycode 49 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

do you know what the problem might be?

As far as I understand it the [man page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html) says that *remove* only works for modifiers, but I don't care for modifiers, I want to switch regular keys. Might there be another problem that is not related to that 'possible duplicate'?

Comment: See the dup, you need to remove them and then map them afterwards.

Comment: @slm The answer marked as duplicate is about modifiers, mine is about regular keys. The man page says remove only applies to modifiers.

Comment: If you take out the `keycode 94 =` can you get the `keycode 49 =` to work at all? I see what you're talking about in the man page, but before we reopen I just want to be sure, so please bear with me. I'm wondering if you're missing a keysymname on the right side. Also did you try generating a xmodmap file on your system directly? I believe it's `xmodmap -pk`.

Comment: @slm No, keycode 49 just doesn't work. I tried to use `xmodmap -pke` after a fresh reboot to print the current configuration and created a new input file by just switching the numbers 49 and 94, but still only 94 works.

Comment: Ah OK, so there is definitely something else awry here.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old question, it seems to be still relevant today (at least I was facing the same problem) and solved it with this `.Xmodmap` file:

```
keycode 49 = less greater less greater
keycode 94 = dead_circumflex degree dead_circumflex degree
```

The "repetitions" are the mappings for caps-lock.The `dead_circumflex`  allows the creation of accented characters, e.g., `^` followed by `e` will create `ê`, while `asciicircum` just emits the plain character `^`.

Hope this helps.